# user input string and integers in Java

Tags: java, string, int

```
    System.out.print("Name : ");
    String name = in.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Age : ");
    int age = in.nextInt();

    System.out.print("City : ");
    String city = in.nextLine();
```

the output will be :

Name : test

Age : 20

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

when i debug them, it won't read the user input for "city" . but when i changed the data type for "age" to string, it will read. how can i kept the data type of age to int with the system reading the user inputs for city ?

Comment: @athirahhazira94 , you have go through on about nextLine(). Anda kena baca tentang nextLine().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As there is still a new line character in the buffer after reading the age, change it to..

```
System.out.print("Name : ");
String name = in.nextLine();

System.out.print("Age : ");
int age = in.nextInt();
//add
in.nextLine();

System.out.print("City : ");
String city = in.nextLine();
```

Comment: It might be helpful to post *why* that addition is necessary, just for anyone else who comes across this question.

Comment: yes . i agree with @dennis . why does it necessary ?

Comment: I agree too, so it is now done

Answer (score 1):

There is still a new line character in the buffer after reading the age.  Try adding a `in.nextLine` before you ask for the city value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
System.out.print("Age : ");
int age = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```