# Skip over inputing string

Tags: java

```
int id;
float grade; 
String name;
Scanner z= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Give the id:\n");
id=z.nextInt();
System.out.println("your id is :"+id+"\n");

System.out.println("Give the name:");
name=z.nextLine();
System.out.println("your name is :"+name);

System.out.println("Give the grade:\n");
grade=z.nextFloat();
```

The problem goes like this.It inputs the integer but when it comes to the String, it prints *"Give the name"* but it doesn't waits until I type something, it skips to the next instruction.

Why's that?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485407/user-input-string-and-integers-in-java/19485423#19485423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `input.nextInt()` command it only reads the int value. So when you continue reading with input.nextLine() you receive the "\n" Enter key. So to skip this you have to add the input.nextLine()

```
id  = z.nextInt();
System.out.println ("your id is :"+id+"\n");
z.nextLine ();// add this line between the next line read

System.out.println("Give the name:");
```

or

```
id = Integer.parseInt(z.nextLine());
System.out.println ("your id is :"+id+"\n");
System.out.println("Give the name:");
```

Answer (score 3):

You have used `name=z.nextLine()`, hence such behavior, Replace it with `name=z.next()`. Below is the edited code:

```
int id;
float grade; 
String name;

Scanner z= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Give the id:\n");
id=z.nextInt();
System.out.println("your id is :"+id+"\n");

System.out.println("Give the name:");
name=z.next();
System.out.println("your name is :"+name);

System.out.println("Give the grade:\n");
grade=z.nextFloat();
```

Answer (score 2):

When you read `int` value using [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29), it reads **only** the `int` value, it skips the new line character. The latter will be read in the next [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) causing it to skip the "real" input.

You can fix this by adding another `nextLine` before the "real" `nextLine`, it'll swallow the `'\n'` that you don't want to read.

**Important note**: Don't use `int` to store ID value! Use `String` instead!

Comment: What's the reason behind using string type for id's instead of int?

Comment: @Matt Imagine an ID: 3423334253 - `int` can't store this.